# civivolunteer error creating event volunteer opportunities through event tab

Tags: error, civivolunteer

After creating an event and clicking on the volunteers tab to create a volunteer project, I try to add the volunteer opportunities on the same screen.  However I don't get the popup and I get these error messages in the browser console:

3SCRIPT438: SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'volunteerPopup'
admin.php (59,7)

0: Object doesn't support property or method 'volunteerPopup'
eval code (24) (58,6)

```
WordPress 5.2.4
CiviCRM 4.7.31
CiviVolunteer 4.7.31-2.3.1
```